# Terraform ignore_changes for CodeDeployProvisioningDeploymentId tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-aws-modules

I'm using Terraform v0.12.25 with provider.aws v2.70.0.
I have ASG resource defined in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "web" {
  name                      = "CodeDeploy_production_web"
  max_size                  = 40
  min_size                  = 1
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = "0"
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  desired_capacity          = 1
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.web.name
  vpc_zone_identifier       = data.aws_subnet_ids.subnets.ids
  suspended_processes       = []
  tag {
      key                 = "Environment"
      propagate_at_launch = true
      value               = "production"
    }
  tag {
      key                 = "Name"
      propagate_at_launch = true
      value               = "Web_App_production_CD"
    }
  tag {
         key                 = "CodeDeployProvisioningDeploymentId"
         propagate_at_launch = true
         value               = ""
     }
  lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [
        desired_capacity,
        name
      ]
    }
}
```

I want to ignore changes on tag "CodeDeployProvisioningDeploymentId". I've tried adding it to `ignore_changes` block but I didn't succeed in making it work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why do you care about the changes on a tag? ... that should not have any impact on the resource, but there are examples on the documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes

Comment: That is exactly why I want to ignore changes. After initial provisionig this ASG is used in codeDeploy deployments. For the next provisionig I use "terragrunt" before hook to import new ASG state to this resource. But I want changes on that tag to be ignored. So if i have changed nothing in terraform code I want terraform to report "no changes".

Comment: That does not clarify anything ... but that link I posted has an example how to ignore a specific tag, in your case it would be something like: `lifecycle { ignore_changes = [ tags["CodeDeployProvisioningDeploymentId"] ] }`

Comment: @Aleksandar did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @PhilippKyeck see my answer below, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There is an [ignore_tags argument on the AWS provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/2.70.0/docs#ignore_tags). However for AWS provider v2.70.0 it says it doesn't work on aws_autoscaling_group resources. I am using AWS provider v3.75.0 and the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.75.0/docs#ignore_tags) for that version doesn't exclude aws_autoscaling_group resources and I can confirm it works.

My provider now looks like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 3.75.0"
  region  = var.aws_region

  ignore_tags {
    keys = ["CodeDeployProvisioningDeploymentId"]
  }
}
```